# Encontrar en lista texto similar al dado

Tags: c#, android, firebase, string, xamarin

Tengo 2 listas donde almaceno el `Nombre` y el `Usuario` de una persona, y necesito cargar otras 2 listas cuando los elementos de las listas coincida con un texto dado.

> Texto dado: ***Ramirez***

> Nombre: Juan Ramirez

> Usuario: Juan.Ramirez_G

El problema es que no me funciona siempre, lo hago de esta forma:

```
//Busqueda local:
            List<string> LocalUsuarios = new List<string>();
            List<string> LocalNombres = new List<string>();
            List<string> LocalPais = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i< CantidadDocs; i++)
            {
                if (VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosNombres[i].Contains(Txt2.Query)
                || VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosUsuarios[i].Contains(Txt2.Query))
                {
                    LocalUsuarios.Add(VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosUsuarios[i]);
                    LocalNombres.Add(VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosNombres[i]);
                }
            }

            //Limpiar
            VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosNombres.Clear();
            VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosUsuarios.Clear();

            //Valores que coinciden
            VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosNombres.AddRange(LocalNombres);
            VarGlobal.BusquedaUsuariosUsuarios.AddRange(LocalUsuarios);
```

Comment: Deja ver si entendí, tienes dos listas nombre y usuario y quieres retornar 2 listas que contengan los usuarios y nombres que coincidan con determinado texto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filtroNombres = (from n in listaNombres 
                 where n.ToLower().Contains(texto.ToLower()) 
                 select n).ToList();
```

Puedes usar **Linq**, y a través de esta consulta obtendrías todos los nombres que hay en **listaNombre** que coincidan con el texto dado.

Para los usuarios sería lo mismo:

```
var filtroUsuarios = (from u in listaUsuarios
                      where u.ToLower().Contains(texto.ToLower())
                      select u).ToList();
```

Hacemos una consulta **Linq** que nos devuelva todos los usuarios que coincidan con el texto dado.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien pero solo si pongo las mayuscula y minuscula a como esta en la lista. Por ejemplo, si es "Juan Ramirez", tengo que poner "Juan" ya que si pongo "juan" no me lo reconoce.

Comment: @KennyAli, ya lo arreglé revisa